# New email service

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there an email service like Gmail but not overloaded by nicknames?

I need a good IMAP service with quite good capacity of storage. By the way, I would like an account name like name.surname@..

Comment: See https://Fastmail.fm ; In addition to being a subsidiary of Opera they have years of experience running an Email service. Lots of user selectable domains too.

Answer (score 3):

You can register a new domain and use [Google Apps for free](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html). Google Apps includes a fully-featured Gmail, as well calendar and several other Google services.

You'll be able to register accounts like

```
yourname@yourdomain.com
```

For example, I registered a domain with my family name and I'm providing email accounts to all my family

```
me@myfamily.com
brother@myfamily.com
dad@myfamily.com
```

The only cost will be the yearly domain registration cost. A .com or .net domain costs between $5 and $15 per year, other extensions might have a different price.